# Does Steam store my savegames?

Tags: steam

if I install a Steam game on another computer, will my progress from my first computer be available immediately? Or is this game dependent? If not, what's the best way to transfer the progress?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Move My Steam Saves from One HD to Another?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11491/how-can-i-move-my-steam-saves-from-one-hd-to-another)

Comment: @Drake: Only the final part. This is mostly a Steam Cloud question, which isn't mentioned in the other question, however.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If a Steam game supports Steam Cloud, savegames are automatically synced with Steam servers and are available on other computers if you log in with your Steam account. It does not necessarily store all your savegames, e.g. with Civilization V you have 10 savegame slots on Steam Cloud, so when you save a game you have to choose to save there, else the savegame will only be local.

You can use [this search](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?adv=0&term=&category1=&developer=&publisher=&category2=23&genre=&priceLow=&priceHigh=) to find a list of Steam Cloud games.

For games that don't support this you could try synchronization with online storage providers like Dropbox, I never tried this myself but it should be possible. Most games have their savegame data somewhere in you personal home directory, often inside the "my games" folder.

Comment: Dropbox works great for synchronizing non-Steamclouded games. I use it for Skryim and some other titles. Usually the best way is to create a junction from the savegame folder to a location inside the Dropbox ( http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Sync_Other_Folders ).

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the game. Games that use Steam to share data are marked with Steam Cloud in the Steam store but some only sync stuff like stats, so make sure to look up the game's information first.

For games that do not use Steam Cloud, usually the beat way to transfer saves is to copy the savefile from one computer to another. This is stored in a game dependent location.