# Steam installation on another computer

Tags: steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Steam store my savegames?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14203/does-steam-store-my-savegames)

If I install my steam on another computer, will I start my games from where I last saved them?

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, no. You'll need to move over your saved games manually, and how that's done changes from one game to another.

Also, I believe Steam is supposed to keep track of achievements, but it's been hit or miss for me. I kept 2 (out of about 6 or 7) achievements for Portal, but kept all of them for Braid.

Comment: ...except for games that are Steam Cloud enabled, then save and configuration files _should_ be mirrored between computers.