# How do you access your saves across multiple PC's using steam?

Tags: steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Steam store my savegames?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14203/does-steam-store-my-savegames)

I've been playing the adventure game "The Longest Journey" on my laptop and now I want to use my desktop. How do I share the saves across my Steam account?

Or is there no way to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Steam supports sharing saved games across multiple devices with [Steam Cloud](http://steampowered.com/steamworks/ov_cloud.php).

That's the good news. The bad news is that this feature also requires the games to support it and it looks like The Longest Journey is among those that don't.

You can tell if a game will work with Steam Cloud by looking at the game's page in the Steam store: if Steam Cloud is supported, the page will say so in the Game Details section below the title, release date, etc.

You could copy the saved game files yourself so long as you set them up in the correct location on the desktop if you don't plan to switch back and forth between the two machines or don't mind keeping the files in sync manually. According to [this thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=840657), The Longest Journey stores its saved games in `%APPDATA%\The Longest Journey`.

You could use Dropbox to sync the saves between the two locations, possibly setting up a symlink from the save location to your Dropbox folder using [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(WS.10).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The steam save locations are not consistent. Some are in the steam tree, others are in "My Game Saves" and still others go into the AppData area.

I know this isn't a direct answer to the question of this one title, and more of a generic answer, but here's a site to bookmark that has lots of game save locations:

[savelocations.wikia.com](http://savelocations.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Games)

Hope this helps in some way, maybe in the future. I find it very useful.