# How to transfer save files, not the game itself on steam

Tags: steam

So I recently just bought a PC to replace my Mac. I know I can copy the game itself onto a flash drive and spare myself the download time but my flash drive isn't big enough. I can download the games again if needed. What I'm concerned about are the specific save files on my computer. My progress in games like Hotline Miami, Papers Please, Plague Inc. etc. Is there a way to transfer the save files and not the game itself?

Comment: This depends entirely on the game itself.  We can't provide an answer for every single game on Steam, but if there's a specific game you want to know about, specify that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move my Steam saves from One hard drive to another?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11491/how-can-i-move-my-steam-saves-from-one-hard-drive-to-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the games use steam cloud, Steam should be saving the savefiles for you.

Otherwise you have to identify the location of each savefile folder of each game, copy it, and put it in the corresponding location on the new machine.

Answer (score 1):

So one of the nice things that you can get from Steam is the ability to upload any of your saves to the Cloud and then it will allow you to synch up the game so it downloads what you uploaded.

For other games you would see save files in ProgramFiles/Steam/SteamApps/Common/"Game"/Save 
Some saves can be located in additonal files, sometimes; /bin, /binaries it can change place to place.

For Papers please you would locate the save here:

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\3909\PapersPlease

Hotline Miama:

In Original version: "\steamapps\common\hotline_miami" and then you have all the files "achievements.dat", "keyboard.dat", "mask.nfo", "saves.dat", "stats.sav", and "tempsave.sav" which contain all the info about your progression (and settings in case of "keyboard.dat").

In Updated version: there's only one save file, located under "C:\Users\\Documents\My Games\HotlineMiami\SaveData.sav"